Show that function is positive definite
In the process of showing that the function\begin{equation}
\langle \mathbf{z}, \mathbf{w}\rangle=\overline{z_1}w_1+(1+i)\overline{z_1}w_2+(1-i)\overline{z_2}w_1+3\overline{z_2}w_2
\end{equation} is an inner product on $\mathbb{C}^2$, I have gotten stuck on the positive definite part.
After many attempts of expansion and rearranging, I have finally given up and have decided to come here for help. Here is what I have so far:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\langle \mathbf{z},\mathbf{z} \rangle
&=\overline{z_1}z_1+(1+i)\overline{z_1}z_2+(1-i)\overline{z_2}z_1+3\overline{z_2}z_2\\
&=|z_1|^2+(1+i)\overline{z_1}z_2+(1-i)\overline{z_2}z_1+3|z_2|^2.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
I have tried playing around with the $3|z_2|^2$ so that I can factor the entire expression in pairs...
Pls help.

Note that if either $z_1=0$ or $z_2=0$, then $\langle \mathbf z,\mathbf z\rangle = |z_1|^2 + 3|z_2|^2 \geq 0$, with equality iff $z_1 = z_2 = 0$. So you only need to consider $z_1\neq 0$ and $z_2\neq 0$. Also, the sum of the two middle terms is equivalent to $2\operatorname{Re}(\bar z_1z_2) - 2\operatorname{Im}(\bar z_1z_2)$. Is this helpful?

What is the significance of the phrase "positive definite" ?

@user2661923 : This means $\langle \mathbf{z},\mathbf{z} \rangle \geq 0$ with equality iff $\mathbf z = \mathbf 0$ (i.e., $z_1 = z_2 = 0$).

Hint:$$\langle\mathbf{z},\mathbf{z}\rangle = |z_1|^2 + (1 + i)\overline{z_1}z_2 + (1 - i)\overline{z_2}z_1 + |1 + i|^2|z_2|^2 + |z_2|^2.$$

Im guessing we after this hint, it would be logical to write $|1+i|^2$ as $(1+i)(1-i)$? But then is factorisation possible? Or should we again consider Re and Im as suggested above? I'm still a little lost

@PeterChen I was hoping to nudge you towards$$\langle\mathbf{z},\mathbf{z}\rangle = |z_1 + (1 + i)z_2|^2 + |z_2|^2.$$From here, if $\langle\mathbf{z},\mathbf{z}\rangle=0$, then $z_1 + (1 + i)z_2 = 0$ and $z_2 = 0$, which then implies $z_1 = 0$.

i very see. an oversight on my behalf. Thank you theo

One way to factor the entire expression in pairs
is by forming the standard inner product of the vector
$$\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\,\begin{pmatrix} (1+i)\,z_2\\
(1-i)\,z_1 + 2z_2\end{pmatrix}$$
with itself. In terms of matrix multiplication one has
$$\begin{align} & \frac1{\sqrt{2}}\big((1-i)\,\overline{z_2}\,,\,
(1+i)\,\overline{z_1} + 2\overline{z_2}\,\big)\;
\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} (1+i)\,z_2\\
 (1-i)\,z_1 + 2z_2\end{pmatrix}\\[5ex]
 & \;=\;\frac12\Big[\big((1-i)\,\overline{z_2}\big)\big((1+i)\,z_2\big)
 + \big((1+i)\,\overline{z_1}+ 2\overline{z_2}\big)\big((1-i)\,z_1+2z_2\big)\Big]\\[5ex]
 & \;=\;\overline{z_1}z_1+(1+i)\,\overline{z_1}z_2+(1-i)\,\overline{z_2}z_1+3\,\overline{z_2}z_2
\;=\;\langle\mathbf{z}, \mathbf{z}\rangle\end{align}$$
which confirms positive definiteness.
How may one arrive at the above?
The proposed inner product can be written as matrix product
$$\langle\mathbf{z}, \mathbf{w}\rangle \:=\: (\,\overline{z_1}\,,\,\overline{z_2}\,)
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1+i\\ 1-i & 3\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} w_1\\ w_2\end{pmatrix}\,,$$
where the central $2\times 2$-matrix $S$ is self-adjoint, and in particular positive-definite: both eigenvalues are strictly positive since $\,1=\det(S)=$ the product of the eigenvalues, and $\,4=\operatorname{trace}(S)=$ the sum of its eigenvalues.
Look out for a self-adjoint square root of $S$: the ansatz $\,Q^2=S\,$ leads to a system of 3 quadratic equations for the matrix entries of $Q$, which is solved by
$$\frac1{\sqrt 2}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1+i\\ 1-i & 2\end{pmatrix}\,.$$
(Notice that this solution is neither unique nor positive-definite.) $\:$Then
$$\frac1{\sqrt 2}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1+i\\ 1-i & 2\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} z_1\\ z_2\end{pmatrix}
 \;=\;\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\,\begin{pmatrix} (1+i)\,z_2\\
(1-i)\,z_1 + 2z_2\end{pmatrix} $$
gives the initial vector which does the desired job.
